# Excel VBA dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown list where it gets the data from a table called table1 in the SQL Server 2005. There is a button next to the drop downlist to add new data to table1. when I click the button and successfully add the new record to table1, I don't see this new added record in my dropdownlist. I have to close the excel sheet and reopen it to see the new added value.
Is there a way to refresh or do something so that I see the new added data right away in the dropdown list after adding it ?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add a call to the procedure that updates the list for the combobox at the end of the 'add new data' button code.

If you can post both the code for the 'add data' button and the `Workbook_Open` procedure then it should be possible to suggest a fix.